# Combination of words in string in Python without using itertools

Tags: python, string, combinations, python-itertools, cpu-word

Is there any way to get all combination of DYNAMIC string's word without using itertools.

ex:
s = "James is King"
O/P:
James is King
is James King
King is James
King James is
is King Jame
James King is

s = "Big Small"
O/P:
Big Small
Small Big

The script should work with any string size

`s = 'big small print([" ".join[i,j] for i in s.split() for j in s.split() if i!=j])`

Above can be done, only if we know the words in string and then have to specify that number of variables inside the join.

Comment: "without using itertools" yeah, implement the same algorithm as `itertools`, python in general, is open source. Or just look at the `itertools` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), where they give you (nearly equivalent, alebit sometimes less efficient) pure python implementations

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
def generate_word_combinations(s):
    words = s.split()
    if len(words) == 1:
        return [s]
    else:
        result = []
        for i in range(len(words)):
            first_word = words[i]
            remaining_words = words[:i] + words[i+1:]
            for combo in generate_word_combinations(' '.join(remaining_words)):
                result.append(first_word + ' ' + combo)
        return result
```